# Pycharm aws lambda debug on container fail with error SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x96' in file /var/lang/bin/python3.9

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, encoding

I'm trying to debug an aws lambda which runs on a docker container using pycharm.
for some reason, only when trying to debug I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x96' in file /var/lang/bin/python3.9 on line 2, but no encoding declared; see https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
time="2023-03-22T12:28:18.304" level=error msg="Init failed" InvokeID= error="Runtime exited with error: exit status 1"
```

with Run everything works well.
this is my template.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description:

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
    MemorySize: 128

Resources:
  SingleStoreFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      ImageConfig:
          Command: [ "app.lambda_handler" ]
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
    Metadata:
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
      DockerContext: ./
      DockerTag: v1
```

this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM localhost:6000/ss-gs-3.9:latest

COPY . ./

CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

the `localhost:6000/ss-gs-3.9:latest` image is pre-built from this dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

COPY XXXX ./ 
COPY XXX ./

RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt 
RUN yum install glibc-all-langpacks 
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8 
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8 
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8

CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

Any Ideas what can be done?
since it's inside the python package it is not relevant for me to add the encoding flag
I also tried with python 3.7 and 3.8

Comment: Why are you trying to run Python on itself?

Comment: Can you check in `app.py` for any `– ` and replace with `-`?

Comment: I don't have any '- ' in my code